# Как преобразовать значение даты и времени в массиве объектов в формат Timestamps?

Tags: javascript

1 Необходимо преобразовать значение даты и времени (переменная `item.TimeString`) в милисекунды от 1970.

Для теста создал новую переменную `var date`, чтобы посмотреть, чего получается - не получается!

2 Код:

```
function completeFn({data}) { //data.forEach(function(row, index) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    var ready = data.map(function(item) {return [item.TimeString,parseInt(item.VarValue)]}); //
    var date = Math.floor(Date(ready.TimeString));}
   console.log(ready);
   console.log(date);
```

3 Переменная `item.TimeString` выглядит так:

```
0: Array [ "29.05.2019 16:42:153600000", 0 ]
​
1: Array [ "29.05.2019 16:42:163600000", 0 ]
​
2: Array [ "29.05.2019 16:42:173600000", 0 ]
​
3: Array [ "29.05.2019 16:42:183600000", 0 ]
​
4: Array [ "29.05.2019 16:42:183600000", 4 ]
​
5: Array [ "29.05.2019 16:42:193600000", 4 ]
​
6: Array [ "29.05.2019 16:42:203600000", 4 ]
​
```

4 Пример как надо:

```
0: Array [ "29.05.2019 16:42:153600000", 0 ]  -  0: Array [ 1559148136, 0 ]
```

Comment: А как надо интерпретировать время `16:42:163600000`? 16 часов 42 минуты 163600000 секунд? 16 часов 42 минуты 163600000 миллисекунд? 16 часов 42 минуты 16 секунд, 360 миллисекунд? И кстати, какое тут время, локальное или UTC? В общем, укажите, какой именно ожидается результат для приведенной строки.

Comment: @Yaant,16 часов 42 минуты 16 сек., что такое 3600000 - пока не знаю. Время локальное.

Comment: @Yaant, для `16:42:16` - 1559148136

Comment: 1559148136 - это же не в миллисекундах, а в секундах, причем все-таки UTC. Вы уж определитесь :)

Comment: @Yaant, Определился )), в миллисекундах 16:42:16 - 1559148136000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать библиотеку [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/):

```js
let timeStr = '29.05.2019 16:42:163600000';
let time = moment.utc(timeStr, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss');
console.log(+time);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha256-4iQZ6BVL4qNKlQ27TExEhBN1HFPvAvAMbFavKKosSWQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо, за быстрый ответ.